# TornadoFX DataGrid with ScrollPane

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I have a project where I am using a `DataGrid` and it is very important that cells stay in the rows they were originally intended to be in (as it is rendering a data structure).

As the number of items in the `DataGrid` gets large, the available width starts being an issue. To combat this, I placed the `DataGrid` inside a `ScrollPane`, with

```kotlin
isFitToWidth = true
```

However, only a vertical scroll bar will appear, and a horizontal one never seems to materialise, causing cells to be forced onto lower rows.

I have implemented it as follows:

```kotlin
private val data = foo
...
scrollpane {
    datagrid(data) {
        ...
    }

    isFitToWidth = true
}
...
```

Have I misunderstood the component?

Comment: *"However, only a vertical scroll bar will appear, and a horizontal one never seems to materialise"* That's exactly what `fitToWidth=true` means; the content of the scroll pane is forced to be the width of the scroll pane's viewport.

Comment: @James_D Then I have misunderstood the purpose of `fitToWidth`. Is there a way to force a scroll bar appearance once a certain width is reached?

Comment: By default, a horizontal scroll bar will appear if the width of the content is greater than the width of the viewport.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that the `DataGrid` still decides to use fewer cells than `maxCellsInRow` and instead move the next cell to a new line, even if embedded in a `ScrollPane`

Comment: Even without the `fitToWidth = true`

Comment: Probably either the max or pref width of the data grid is forcing that to happen. You should post a [mre] (though you'll probably still have to wait for a kotlin/TornadoFX person to answer it; I don't speak kotlin).